# What results from the neutralization of copper citrate with Na2CO3

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, everyday-chemistry

I found [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/147891/129379) that describes PCB etching with citric acid. [The answer to that question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/147901/129379) explains how hydrogen peroxide, salt, and citric acid can be used to ionize copper metal in water, which provides:

$$\ce{Cu + H2O2 + 2 H+ -> Cu^{2+} + 2 H2O}$$

The equation above excludes the citrate ion, so maybe it isn't party to the reaction.  This observation prompted the following:

**Question:**

- Assuming the citric acid ion is [$\ce{C6H7O7^-}$](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Citric-acid-ion), what is the equation for the neutralization reaction (I kept $\ce{H^+}$ in this, but it's been a while since highschool/college chem, this may not be represented right):

$$\ce{Cu^{2+} + C6H7O7^- + H^+ + Na2CO3 -> } ??? $$

- What remains ionized in solution after neutralizing with $\ce{Na2CO3}$?
- Will there be a precipitate? If so, what?

(This will inform our choices for responsible disposal.  I'm not sure what other details to provide, as this seems like a pretty simple question.  Let me know if you need more information.)

Comment: You don’t dispose of any chemicals down the drain. Check your municipal hazardous waste disposal folks.

Comment: You would prepare a variant of [Benedict reagent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedict%27s_reagent), copper kept in stable citrate complex. If you added glucose and boil, the blue solution would start to form yellow to brick read insoluble cuprous oxide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copper ion forms with citrate stable chalate, that is not disturbed even by addition of sodium carbonate, what is used in [Benedict's reagent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedict%27s_reagent)(*) for detection of reducing sacharides.

Copper etching:

$$\ce{Cu(s) + H2O2(aq) + H4Citr(aq) ->  2 H2O(l) + CuH2Citr(aq)}$$

Solution neutralization:

$$\ce{2 CuH2Citr(aq) + CO3^2-(aq) -> H2O(l) + CO2(g) + 2 [HCuCitr]-(aq)}$$
$$\ce{[CuHCitr]-(aq) + CO3^2-(aq) -> HCO3-(aq) + [CuCitr]^2-(aq)}$$

Copper can be eliminated by reducting agents, like glucose, or perhaps by sulphite/bisulphite, forming insoluble copper(I) oxide.

---

> (*) Benedict's reagent  is a deep-blue aqueous solution. Each litre contains:
>
> $\pu{17.3 g}$ copper sulfate
> $\pu{173 g}$ sodium citrate
> $\pu{100 g}$ anhydrous sodium carbonate or, equivalently, 270g sodium carbonate decahydrate

Comment: Does no positive ion exist in solution after neutralization?  I ask because (perhaps this is where my chem knowledge breaks down) I had always thought you needed both positive _and_ negative ions in the solution.  You wrote $\ce{-> HCO3-(aq) + [CuCitr]^2-(aq)}$ and both ions are negative.  So is the result really a solution of only negative ions?

Comment: There are no solutions with only negative ions. Positive ions like Na+(aq) are called here bystanding/spectator ions, not taking part in reactions, just maintaining electroneutrality.

Comment: So the NaCl that was added to the [original etching solution](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/147891/how-exactly-does-copper-react-with-hydrogen-peroxide-salt-and-citric-acid) remains Na+ and Cl- through the entire process, from etching to neutralization?

Comment: True for Na+. Cl- takes part in parallel reactions of oxidation to Cl2 by H2O2, reaction of Cl2 with Cu and forming weak complex with Cu^2+.

Comment: So does Cl2 remain in solution, or can it come out as Cl2(g)?

Comment: I case of concentrated solutions of HCl  + H2O2, Cl2(g) would be formed. In our case it would stay as minor product of side reactions.